# Generalize the method signature of a function in haskell.

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and trying to see how it works. 
I want to define a function in Haskell that could take a list of tuples, those tuples could be pair, 3-tuple, 4-tuple, 5-tuple and etc

```
functionY [(a,b)]
```

Then I cannot call it with 3-tuple element like `[(1,2,3),(2,3,4)]`

```
functionY  [(1,2,3),(2,3,4)] // will complain
```

How would I fix this?
thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible - since tuples are highly specific types and they don't have their own typeclass either. In GHC, [Data.Tuple](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Data-Tuple.html) itself only speaks about pairs. Others may chime in to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Okay, some searching around gave me: [Yampa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Yampa-0.9.2.3/docs/src/FRP-Yampa-Miscellany.html) and [tuple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple) package. Have a look at their source to see how they deal with this. They do define multiple functions for n-tuples. tuple package use fundeps to tackle this.

Comment: Another option is to overload `functionY` by putting it in a typeclass.

Comment: Lens also generalises over tuples, but it requires a bit of hackery on the type level, and is nothing you will do when you are new to Haskell.

Comment: Ignoring the compiler errors, how would you write `functionY`?

Comment: I've wondered whether it would be useful to treat all tuples as the same in some contexts, even being able to split them into a head item and tail tuple. Obviously there are issues with that - components have different types etc. There's still some sense to it, and it doesn't require dynamic typing - it's more like metaprogramming. In fact C++ templates already allow you to handle a tuple of any size by recursing for one component at a time - no dynamic typing needed as the recursion is all done at compile-time. That suggests maybe it's possible to do something similar with Template Haskell.

Comment: @Steve314 Template Haskell is not needed; see [HList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList), which only uses TH for the non-essential `MakeLabels` module.

Comment: @Daniel - tuples as heterogenous lists? I'm not sure I understand, or that it's what I meant, but I'll take a proper look a bit later. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Steve314 The conceptual progression goes like this: `(a, b, c, d)` is roughly the same as `(a, (b, (c, (d, ()))))`; writing `cons = (,)` and `nil = ()` we could then have a value `cons a (cons b (cons c (cons d nil)))` in this type; and then, gosh, doesn't that look a bit like a heterogeneous list!

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach, which is suitable if you don't mind writing a bit of boilerplate code. Conceptually, all that matters about an *n*-tuple is that it is a data structure with *n* slots that you can get access to. Every n-tuple for *n >= m* should have a method called get-*m* that gets whatever data is in the *m*'th slot. We can abstract that into a typeclass by using functional dependencies

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class HasFirst a b | a -> b where
    get1 :: a -> b

class HasSecond a b | a -> b where
    get2 :: a -> b
```

Those type classes describe data that have a "first" and a "second" slot. We can write instances for 2-tuples and 3-tuples as follows

```
instance HasFirst (a,b) a where
    get1 (a,_) = a

instance HasSecond (a,b) b where
    get2 (_,b) = b

instance HasFirst (a,b,c) a where
    get1 (a,_,_) = a

instance HasSecond (a,b,c) b where
    get2 (_,b,_) = b
```

Now you can write a function that is generic over all data structures that have a "second" slot, for example

```
getSeconds :: HasSecond a b => [a] -> [b]
getSeconds = map get2
```

And use it as follows

```
>>> getSeconds [(1,2), (4,5)]
[2,5]
>>> getSeconds [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
[2,5]
```